# Currency format in google apps script

Tags: google-apps-script

I have created some set of rows for a requirement gathering document in which for a range I have set numberformat for USD as

```
ex_range.setNumberFormat("[$$]#");
```

upon execution, in the range when the user enters the value, the formatting rounds it to a whole number.

I tried

```
ex_range.setNumberFormat("[$$]#,##0.0000");
```

and for the above, when the user enters a value say e.g. `34.56` I get `$34.5600`

I want the user to enter the value and whatever decimal points they enter to not round off or add extra zeros.

If the user enters `50.67`, I should get `$50.67` and if `45.5670` is entered I should get `$45.5670`

Please help in how to set the format to USD for the range and no round up happens to the values.

I am having the user fill value in the range `K43:P57`, they should be able to enter any value with any decimal number, the value should not get rounded off.

[image]

and the script should read the range `K43:P57`and identify the value with highest decimal numbers and populate in `G43`

Comment: About `If the user enters 50.67, I should get $50.67 and if 45.5670 is entered I should get $45.5678`, I cannot understand the logic for retrieving `$45.5678` from `45.5670`. Can I ask you about the detailed logic for achieving your goal?

Comment: oops sorry, if 45.5670 is entered then it should be $45.5670. it was a typo, I have updated the question too

Comment: Thank you for replying. I understood it. About `45.5670`, when `45.5670` is put to a cell, I think that `45.5670` is converted to `45.567`. In your situation, even when `45.5670` is put to a cell, you want to display `45.5670` in a cell. Is my understanding correct?

Comment: yes @Tanaike -san thats correct, even when 45.5670 is put to a cell, I want to display 45.5670 in a cell

Comment: Thank you for replying. I understood it. And, I noticed that an answer has already been posted. In this case, I would like to respect the existing answer.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/250679/discussion-between-alicia-stone-and-tanaike).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With an `onEdit(e)` function you can set the number format for the edited cell. This will override the column formatting. Be aware that the `0` at the end of `5.989830` will be "cut off" before sending it to the script. So the value of `n` inside the script below will be `5.98983` like [@Tanaike](https://stackoverflow.com/users/7108653/tanaike) is mentioning in the comments. Nevertheless i hope this will help:

**EDIT:** If the original column formatting is `Plain text` the solution below will work with tailing zero's

1. Extensions -> Apps script.
2. Paste the code.
3. Change the sheetname and column number to the values where theformatting needs to happen.
4. Save an quit.
5. Test it out.

```
function onEdit(e) {
  //Settings
  const sheetname = "BB";

  //Rest of script
  const sheet = e.source.getActiveSheet();
  const range = e.range;
  const n = e.value;

  if (isNaN(n)) return;
  if (sheet.getName() !== sheetname) return;
  
  const column = range.getColumn();
  if (column < 11) return;
  if (column > 16) return;
  
  const row = range.getRow();
  if (row < 43) return;
  if (row > 57) return;

  const length = n.toString().split(".")[1].length;
  const zeros = new Array(length).fill("0").join("");
  const format = "#,##0." + zeros;

  range.setNumberFormat(format);
}
```

Comment: Thank you @ RemcoE33, very kind of you for the answer, I updated my question to cover the broader picture

Comment: @AliciaStone see update. Please be precise with your questions. The highest deciamal can be found with native sheet formula's. Look into `FLATTEN()` and `MAX()`

Answer (score 3):

Why not just use something like:

```
 var price = Utilities.formatString("$%.2f", number);
```

Seems easier than the other proposed solutions?